# SQL percentage query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(KDV_Haric_Ciro) AS Ciro
     , Ana_Kategori
  FROM general_Table
 Where EczaneID = $pharmacy_id
   AND Yil = '$dateYear'
 GROUP 
    BY Ana_Kategori
 ORDER 
    BY Ciro DESC
```

but I want the results in percentage.

Currently the results are like this:

```
A 5
B 7
C 8
```

I have tried nested queries with percentage methods but all failed.

Comment: Before you make another move, see about the importance of parametrised queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a percentage, you need the total.  For that, you need another calculation.  One method is:

```
SELECT gt.Ana_Kategori, SUM(gt.KDV_Haric_Ciro) AS Ciro,
       SUM(gt.KDV_Haric_Ciro) / total.KDV_Haric_Ciro as ratio
FROM general_Table gt CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT SUM(gt2.KDV_Haric_Ciro) as KDV_Haric_Ciro
      FROM general_Table gt2
      WHERE gt2.EczaneID = '".$pharmacy_id."' AND gt2.Yil = '".$dateYear."'
     ) total
WHERE gt.EczaneID = '".$pharmacy_id."' AND gt.Yil = '".$dateYear."'
GROUP BY gt.Ana_Kategori
ORDER BY `Ciro` DESC;
```

Note:  You should not be munging query strings with parameter values.  You should learn how to write parameterized queries.

Comment: gives #1054 - Unknown column 'gt2.EczaneID' in 'where clause' error

Comment: @shivzuh If you know how to create the query above, you should know how to fix the error.  It's just the wrong alias.